# error with jQuery AJAX on Safari and iOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, safari

I have a compatibility issue with Safari and all iOS devices. I created this jQuery code (see the link below ) for a project but I don't understand why it doesn't work with Safari.
With the Chrome, Firefox, Android it works well.

```
(function ($) {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  const ajax_dir = '/wp-content/plugins/oxygen-functions/assets/ajax/';
  
  // SELECT LOCATION-SERVICE FORM

  $('.serv-select select').html(select_vars.services_select);
  $('.loc-select select').html(select_vars.locations_select);
  $('.service-location-form')
    .closest('form')
    .submit(async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).find('.frm_message').addClass('d-none');

      var form = $(this).serializeArray(),
        service = form.find((x) => x['name'] == `item_meta[33]`).value,
        loc = form.find((x) => x['name'] == `item_meta[34]`).value,
        cat = loc + ',' + service,
        posts = await $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          async: true,
          url: ajax_dir + 'posts-by-cat.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            post_type: 'services',
            cat: cat,
          },
        }),
        url = await $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          async: true,
          url: ajax_dir + 'post-link-id.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            id: posts[0],
          },
        });
      //console.log(url);
      location.href = url;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the error that I getting from the DevConsole:

[image]

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection [object Object]
  (anonymous function) - scripts.js:21
  asyncFunctionResume
  (anonymous function)
  promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise
```

How I can fix it? some idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You're using an `async` function to submit.

Comment: I am using that function to generate a link between two types of CPT. It was the only solution to create a dropdown menu where you can select option1, option2 --> submit --> go to the right link.

Comment: You do need to `event.preventDefault()` on`submit` if you are using a form and have a button that submits *(so a real submit doesn't happen)*, but you don't have to force an actual `submit` Event when using AJAX. You can simply use a `change` Event to trigger AJAX. Actual form submission is old school. Get rid of the `async` and `await`s, in your case either way. `xhr` would be returned immediately with those `await`s... and you don't want your jQuery Event function to return anything anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code doesn't have any error catching blocks.

Try to insert the function content into the `try/catch` block

```js
(function ($) {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  const ajax_dir = '/wp-content/plugins/oxygen-functions/assets/ajax/';
  
  // SELECT LOCATION-SERVICE FORM

  $('.serv-select select').html(select_vars.services_select);
  $('.loc-select select').html(select_vars.locations_select);
  $('.service-location-form')
    .closest('form')
    .submit(async function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      try {

        $(this).find('.frm_message').addClass('d-none');

        var form = $(this).serializeArray(),
        service = form.find((x) => x['name'] == `item_meta[33]`).value,
        loc = form.find((x) => x['name'] == `item_meta[34]`).value,
        cat = loc + ',' + service,
        posts = await $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          async: true,
          url: ajax_dir + 'posts-by-cat.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            post_type: 'services',
            cat: cat,
          },
        }),
        url = await $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          async: true,
          url: ajax_dir + 'post-link-id.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            id: posts[0],
          },
        });
        //console.log(url);
        location.href = url;
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        // Handle error here. - maybe ajax fail
      }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any more issues according to this one.

Comment: Hey @StefanWang thanks million for your follow up. I didn't fix the issue with your snippet. A friend of mine suggested me to use "e.stopImmediatePropagation();"

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your information. Anyway, nice to hear that you've solved the issue. Will you please post an answer here so that others can refer in the future?

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole snippet:

```
(function ($) {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  const ajax_dir = '/wp-content/plugins/oxygen-functions/assets/ajax/'; 
  // SELECT LOCATION-SERVICE FORM

  $('.serv-select select').html(select_vars.services_select);
  $('.loc-select select').html(select_vars.locations_select);

  var closestForm = $('.service-location-form').closest('form');

  closestForm.submit(async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // <-- I fixed my issue with it

    $(this).find('.frm_message').addClass('d-none');

    var form = $(this).serializeArray();
    var service = form.find((x) => x['name'] == `item_meta[33]`).value;
    var loc = form.find((x) => x['name'] == `item_meta[34]`).value;
    var cat = loc + ',' + service;
    try {
      var posts = await $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        async: true, // true was a string
        url: ajax_dir + 'posts-by-cat.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          post_type: 'services',
          cat: cat,
        },
      });
    } catch (safariError) {
      console.error(safariError);
    }

    var url = await $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      async: true, // also was 'true'
      url: ajax_dir + 'post-link-id.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        id: posts[0],
      },
    });

    //console.log(url);
    location.href = url;
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return false;
```

Try using a `return false` statement after ajax call

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.